# AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'runandload'

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to load a layer after its creation, by using `runadload()`, but I am getting the error: `AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'runandload'.`

Here's the partial script:

```
processing.runandload("native:saveselectedfeatures", {
        'INPUT':boundary_layer,
        'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

I am on QGIS3.4 Mac version and the processing version is 2.12.99. I tested the same script on QGIS3.6 to no avail. Is it that `runandload()` has been replaced in version 3, and if yes, what is the substitute?

Comment: The current method is `processing.runAndLoadResults()`